# How do I mine redstone ore on Minecraft Pocket Edition 0.7.0

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I found redstone ore but whatever I do it just gets destroyed. I have used every tool but I cant figure it out I have the updated version 0.7.0 so i think that has something to do with it? Please help!

Comment: what do you mean??

Comment: This question has already been asked.  In order to ensure that answers for the same thing stay in the same spot, we close questions that have already been asked and link them to the original.

Comment: i just want an answer the other one i looked at but i didn